# EC2 high stolen time without load

Tags: amazon-ec2

I can see very high % of stolen time on a EC2 web server (t2.micro) without any load (one current user) with a high page load time. Is there a correlation between hight load time and hight stolen time? I have the same symptoms with another server from class t2.medium

Do you have an explanation?

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0      0  79824   7428 479172    0    0     0     0   52   49 18  0  0  0 82
 1  0      0  79792   7436 479172    0    0     0     6   54   49 18  0  0  0 82
 1  0      0  79824   7444 479172    0    0     0     5   54   51 18  0  0  0 82
```

Comment: I believe I can explain this, but we need to clear up a misconception, first.  This machine is not "without any load," as userspace CPU utilization `us` is showing 18%.  In the EC2 console, select the instance, select the "Monitoring" tab, and take a look at the graph for "CPU Credit Balance." You should find that it is near zero.  Please confirm.

Comment: Yes you are right. There is a load but this is not what I meant. Sorry! For the moment i don't know why there is this us cpu time but it's another subject. I found this link that explains the meaning of the stolen time in EC2 (https://blog.appdynamics.com/product/a-guide-to-performance-challenges-with-aws-ec2-part-1/) . Thank you for your response which is also interesting.

Comment: Actually that post contains some misinformation.  Any time you read someone invoking the "noisy neighbor" problem regarding EC2, just close that browser tab -- you're dealing with someone who doesn't know what they're talking about.  Please check CPU Credit Balance in the Monitoring tab of the console.